# Remove sidebar from WooCommerce Product Page in bootScore Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I am having difficulty removing the sidebar from a Single Product Page in WooCommerce using the [bootScore Child Theme](https://bootscore.me/).

The first thing I tried was removing the action in my child themes `functions.php` file

```
function remove_sidebar_single_product_page() {
if ( is_product() ) {
    // for default woocommerce structure
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
   }
} 
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_sidebar_single_product_page' );
```

Then I made a copy of the file `single-product.php` to `bootscore-main/woocommerce/single-product.php` and tried to comment out the line   `do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );` but it took no effect so I'm guessing that this file is not the one responsible for serving out the single product page in my WooCommerce shop

Then I looked in the bootScore theme and I see a file called `woocommerce.php` which says

```
/**
 * The template for displaying all WooCommerce pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package Bootscore
 */
```

And on that page I see a call to `<?php  get_sidebar(); ?>` so I commented that out but that had no effect either.

I'm at a loss to know where else the sidebar might be coming from.  I know I can hide the sidebar via css but I'd rather not go down that route. I'd really like to know how the product page is put together and be able to control what templates are writing into the dom.

Where should I look next?

Comment: You should make a copy of the file single-product.php to bootscore **CHILD THEME** > woocommerce > single-product.php intead. If you have a child theme, is to avoid making changes in the main parent theme, without loosing your customizations when the main theme get updated ! Now often the themes make their own customizations against WooCommerce default. So you may have to find out that in your main theme, or ask/search in the theme author's support pages.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar is dynamic and is being shown due to the widgets in it, if you remove all the various widgets from the sidebar then it won't be shown and the main content will span the full width of the page